# What is the reason for this output while creating a child process?

Tags: c, child-process

Just like the title says, how come I'm getting this output while creating a child process? Specifically, why does all of a sudden, the child print or parent print statement will sometimes print faster than the other?

```
CHILD 0
                        PARENT 14
                        PARENT 15
CHILD 1
                        PARENT 16
CHILD 2
                        PARENT 17
.
.
.
CHILD 191
CHILD 192
CHILD 193
CHILD 194
CHILD 195
CHILD 196
CHILD 197
CHILD 198
CHILD 199
CHILD 200
CHILD 201
CHILD 202
CHILD 203
CHILD 204
CHILD 205
CHILD 206
                          PARENT 206
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
  pid_t pid; /* could be int */
  int i;
  pid = fork();

  if( pid > 0 )
  {
    /* parent */
    for( i=0; i < 1000; i++ )
      printf("\t\t\tPARENT %d\n", i);
  }
  else
  {
    /* child */
    for( i=0; i < 1000; i++ )
      printf("CHILD %d\n", i);
  }
 return (0);
}
```

Comment: That's the scheduling algorithm in the kernel of the system you're running on, in combination with what else is running.  The two processes can run concurrently, and on most modern machines with multiple cores, actually do run simultaneously.  When the output from either process appears on the screen depends on factors outside your control.

Comment: oh ok, got it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As I noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56918067/what-is-the-reason-for-this-output-while-creating-a-child-process#comment100378893_56918067):

The interleaved output is a consequence of the scheduling algorithm in the kernel of the system you're running on, in combination with what else is running. The two processes can run concurrently, and on most modern machines with multiple cores, actually do run simultaneously. When the output from either process appears on the screen depends on factors outside your control.  For each process, its own outputs will appear in sequence (so `CHILD 0` appears before `CHILD 1`, and `PARENT 0` appears before `PARENT 1`, etc), but when the outputs from either process appear in relation to the other is mostly indeterminate.